# How to show that the Airy function is Lorentzian

Tags: functions, probability-distributions, physics

The Airy function used to describe the reflected/transmitted intensity of a Fabry-Perot interferometer has the general form:

$$\frac{F\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)}{1+F\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)},$$

where $F$ is a constant known as the Finesse.

What would be a simple way to show that the dips in this function have a Lorentzian shape?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**P. S.** Here is a plot I made that shows the dips that occur in the Airy function described above:[image]

Comment: Not clear how your figure is related to the function that you have just described. In particular, what's the relationship between frequency and $\theta$ or $\sin\theta$. Also, just to make sure I understood correctly, what you want to show is that $$1-\frac{F\sin^2\theta}{1+F\sin^2\theta}$$ is a sum of lorentzians. Am I right?

Comment: Hi there, Yes, that's exactly what I want to show. In the graph above, I had plotted the Airy function as a function of frequency. But if I plot it as a function of phase $\theta$ it will look exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the reflection is $$R=\frac{F\sin^2\theta}{1+F\sin^2\theta}$$
then the transmitted is $$T=1-\frac{F\sin^2\theta}{1+F\sin^2\theta}=\frac{1+F\sin^2-F\sin^2\theta}{1+F\sin^2\theta}=\frac{1}{1+F\sin^2\theta}=\frac 1F\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac 1F}^2+\sin^2\theta}$$